# Spinner selection is the record previous to spinner items being updated

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I fill a spinner via json from a webservice. The spinner gets populated, a selection of index 0 is set, the onitemselected method fires and launches another method to populate a list view based on the value in the spinner.

The problem appears when I refill the spinner with different data. Spinner gets filled, selection of index 0 is set, onitemselected fires and when I output the selected item it shows the previous item at the 0 index. spinneritems.get grabs the old data rather than the newly filled data.

Here is filling the spinner

```
for (int i = 0; i < recordsArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject record = recordsArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
    datum.put("code", record.getString("id") + " - " + record.getString("heading"));
    datum.put("description", record.getString("body"));
    spinneritems.add(datum);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinner.setSelection(0);
}
```

it leads to the firing of

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {    
                populateList(page);
            }
```

which then calls a method with

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.comSpinner);
String spinnerItem = spinneritems.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).get("code");
```

It all works fine the first time it runs, but when I perform an action that changes the spinner contents the method at the end still grabs the old data for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Before setting the adapter initially I do the following

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.comSpinner);
spinneritems.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```